# What does os.O_TRUNC do?

Tags: function, go, module, func, writefile

`func OpenFile(name string, flag int, perm FileMode) (*File, error)`

```
f, err := os.OpenFile("notes.txt", os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE|O_TRUNC, 0755)
```

Does "O_TRUNC" empty the entire file before writing?
What do they mean with "truncates"?

Also, does the function `ioutil.WriteFile()` empty the entire file before writing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There was some confusion on previous definitions of `os.O_TRUNC` using the verbiage "if possible" - see [here](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/28699).

Today the [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#pkg-constants) read:

```
O_TRUNC  int = syscall.O_TRUNC  // truncate regular writable file when opened.
```

So

> Does "O_TRUNC" empty the entire file before writing ?

Yes. It essentially clobbers the file's contents - if the file path exists already (and is a file or symlink to an existing file).

Similarly from [ioutil.WriteFile docs](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#WriteFile):

> ... WriteFile truncates it before writing.

Comment: For ordinary files the file is truncated on opening, which is before writing. And may, in the general case, be arbitrarily long before writing. You can truncate a file by opening it with O_TRUNC and closing it without writing anything.